# Is my understanding of a calorie deficit correct?

Tags: bodybuilding

According to https://tdeecalculator.net, my maintenance calorie level is 2,130 calories per day. A 500 calorie deficit would be 1,630. Does this mean that I try to eat 250 calories less and burn more than 250 calories when exercising? Could you give me an example of how much calories I can limit myself to in a day, and how many calories I must burn?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that individual base calorie requirements vary significantly, so going just off a calculator needs to be taken with a grain of salt.

You need to just log calories and your weight to find your maintenance level, for probably at least a month.  Log your calories and your weight every day, if your weight goes down slightly then your maintenance calories should be slightly higher than what you ate, if your weight is flat then your maintenance will be roughly what you ate, and if it goes up your maintenance is below what you ate.

EDIT: I want to add here, even though I said you should log your weight every day, you should really only look at your weight change over the last week.  There are too many factors which influence day to day weight for a one day difference to be useful.  You can gain wait from one day to the next and still be losing weight overall.

For example I have a fairly slow metabolism.  These calculators say I should be at ~2500 calories per day for maintenance, but measuring my intake and weight it's actually closer to 2000.

The maximum deficit you should be aiming for is whatever has you losing about 0.5kg (or 1 lb) per week.  If you're losing slower than that you can afford to cut a little more, if you're losing faster you should increase it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating your daily maintenance calories, you should factor in your activity level. E.g. if your initial TDEE is 2000, you burn 200cal a day during your exercise then your overall maintenance calories would be 2200.
If you wanted a 500 calorie deficit, you wild then take 500 calories from that and would have daily intake of 1700cal.

What you said is almost right but I just makes more sense to factor in your exercise when calculating cour maintenance.

Exercise is just part of your TDEE.

Comment: So how many calories do i burn, if i do a deficint of 500? my daily maintenence calories with the deficint is 1,630

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you're asking.